# How to permanently remove a device from Device Manager

Tags: usb, windows-10, mouse

For a couple of days now, whenever I start up my PC or Scan for Hardware Changes in Device Manager, a second 'HID-compliant mouse' appears. All this does is constantly move my cursor down, and can only be fixed by disabling it in Device Manager.

I've tried unplugging just about everything from the USB ports and nothing stopped it. So I've come to the conclusion that it's just a phantom device. The problem is that even after disabling and uninstalling it, it still appears whenever I scan for changes or reboot my PC.

Comment: You have tried a different mouse?

Comment: Or try a different port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Examining the rogue device further gave me a name - Saitek. I have a Saitek joystick which is notorious for malfunctioning. So I unplugged it and replugged it and it fixed the problem.